Predicting simulated data for a known curve
I have hit a roadblock with a research problem and could really use your expertise.
I have a pre-existing curve created by extrapolating known fitted experimental data. As shown below, the x-axis is, say, heat given to the sample and y-axis is the response probability Heat vs Response.

I have another dataset for which I have to estimate the decay function. For sample "i" the total heat is defined as
$$
H_{i} = H_{0}\exp^{-kt} + H_{known} \quad{(1)}
$$
where $H_{0}$, t and $H_{known}$ are the known terms. "k" is the unknown term
$H_{i}$ generated from equation1 and its known binary response for all the samples are then binned to get H and response probability.
Below, I am showing a sample figure with green points as the new data, with a randomly picked "k" value. Simulated data in green

My problem is the estimate of the unknown "k" in Equation 1, which minimizes the difference between the green points and the blue curve.
Can someone please suggest an ideal approach to estimate "k"

please use $$ to display equations correctly.

Thanks, I will fix them

Not sure I can give you an ideal approach to estimate $k$. You need to define yourself what good looks like, and the way you estimate it may change depending on how you define it. For example, you could say that your aim is to predict $H_i$ for future times. Do you care about having the absolute error being small, or the error on the logit scale? The reason you may prefer the latter, is that $H_i$ is bounded from top and bottom, so small error in predicting $H_i$ may have different consequences depending on magnitude of $H_i$. In machine learning, one would ask what your 'loss-function' is.
An equivalent way of restate the problem is to ask for a statistical model for your observations, i.e. what is the distribution of your observed $H_i$.
Perhaps, a good place to start might be to convert it into a regression problem. Let $h_i=H_i/H_{known}$ and $h_0=H_0/H_{known}$. Then your equation can be converted into:
$$
\begin{align}
h_i&=1+h_0\exp\left(-kt\right)\\
\log \left(\frac{h_0}{h_i-1}\right)&=k\cdot t
\end{align}
$$
So if you do plot $t$ vs $\log \left(\frac{h_0}{h_i-1}\right)$ with zero intercept, the gradient of the line will be $k$. Mathematically, this would be linear regression of $\log \left(\frac{h_0}{h_i-1}\right)$ on $t$ with zero intercept. Note however, that this would, most likely, be minimizing the squared residuals of $\log \left(\frac{h_0}{h_i-1}\right)$ . It might be a reasonable thing to do, might be not (hence the subtlety with choosing the loss-function/statistical model). Give it a go - might be what you need.
